# Polyglossia and hookrightarrow

Tags: luatex, arrows, polyglossia

Can someone explain why there is a gap between the tail and the head of `\hookrightarrow` when I load `polyglossia` with French support ? I'm using LuaLaTeX for producing the .pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\begin{document}

\Huge $\hookrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: wrong arrow]

Thank you.

Comment: For me it works when using `babel` instead of `polyglossia`, so if that’s a compromise you’re willing to do, go for it.

Comment: french treats punctuation differently -- adds space(s) around some punctuation marks.  `\lhook` (the leftmost piece of `\hookrightarrow`) has the misfortune to be defined (in `fontmath.ltx`) as `\DeclareMathSymbol{\lhook}{\mathrel}{letters}{"2C}`, and `"2C` is in the same location as a comma in a text font.  how to fix it?  don't know ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- that may not be the cause (and egreg has just identified the actual cause), but the coincidence was just too great to ignore, and led to a truly delightfully devious workaround.  so i'm not displeased with my conjecture.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I deleted my comment (and unfortunately had to vote for egreg:(

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your conjecture was very useful and proved true. There are some very mysterious happenings, though, as you can see from my extended answer.

Comment: I opened an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/92

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The callback used by LuaTeX for inserting the penalties and spaces after punctuation should be disabled in math mode, but apparently it isn't.

Workaround until a fix is shipped out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\ifluatex
  \makeatletter
  \let\latex@lhook\lhook
  \renewrobustcmd{\lhook}{%
    \mathrel{\mathpalette\do@lhook\relax}%
  }
  \newcommand{\do@lhook}[2]{%
    \hbox{\directlua{polyglossia.desactivate_frpt()}$\m@th#1\latex@lhook$}%
  }
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}

$\hookrightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course this won't be necessary if `unicode-math` is used.

The problem, as hinted by Barbara Beeton (but not getting the real problem), is that the right arrow happens to occupy the position of exclamation mark in the ASCII code, so LuaTeX blindly applies the penalty and spacing also before it as if it were in text.

The same problem could arise for other math symbols sharing their code point with punctuation symbols.

The characters involved for the OML encoding are

- `\lhook` in the position of `,`
- `\omega` in the position of `!`
- the period in the position of `:`
- `\star` in the position of `?`
- the comma, in the position of `;`
- `>` in the same position as itself.

However, only `\lhook` and `\omega` seem to be affected; more tests with different character combinations should be performed.

In the OMS encoding we have

- `\Leftrightarrow` in the position of `,`
- `\rightarrow` in the position of `!`
- `\lnot` in the position of `:`
- `\bot` in the position of `?`
- `\emptyset` in the position of `;`
- `\top` in the position of `>`

Curiously enough, here `\rightarrow`, `\lnot`, `\bot` and `\emptyset` are affected.

Here's the output of

```
X${\lhook}{\omega}{.}{\star}{,}{>}
  {\Leftrightarrow}{\rightarrow}{\lnot}{\bot}{\emptyset}{\top}$X

\selectlanguage{english}

X${\lhook}{\omega}{.}{\star}{,}{>}
  {\Leftrightarrow}{\rightarrow}{\lnot}{\bot}{\emptyset}{\top}$X
```

used for making the comparison

[image]

I'm quite afraid to see what happens with the OMX encoding: I guess that

Comment: `\mapsto` is also problematic.

Comment: @BigDawg I came to the conclusion that `\rightarrow` is the culprit in `\hookrightarrow` and not `\lhook`. But the principle is the same. And this explains `\mapsto` that has `\rightarrow` in it.

Comment: I know this answer is years old, but I ran into this (actually for `\mapsto`), and this workaround seems to desactivate french spacing in all document. So, what I did is `\renewcommand{\mapsto}{\mathrel{\mathord{\mapstochar}\mathord{\rightarrow}}}`. But let us be honest: I have no idea what I'm doing and this is probably not the right way.

Comment: @ArmandKoenig Oh, that's possible. Support for French has changed quite a lot, in the past years.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nasty fix following barbara beeton's comment, if someone has better...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\Huge \begin{english}$\hookrightarrow$\end{english}$\hookrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

Comment: definitely evil!  (good idea, though.)