# Lualatex, polyglossia, french spacing, and the hole in the hookarrow with egreg fix, in texlive2015/2016

Tags: luatex, arrows, polyglossia, french

This deals with the solution by egreg to fix the hole in the arrows, when we use lualatex and french spacings through polyglossia
[Polyglossia and hookrightarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234487/polyglossia-and-hookrightarrow)

**You can see that, once that the arrow is introduced, there is no space before the semicolon as well as the guillemets, *both before and after the arrow* and that it goes on the next lines in the doc. How to get it back ?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\newcommand{\fff}{f; f ;«f» « f »; $\epsilon$;}
\ifluatex
\makeatletter
\let\latex@lhook\lhook
\renewrobustcmd{\lhook}{%
\mathrel{\mathpalette\do@lhook\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\do@lhook}[2]{%
\hbox{\directlua{polyglossia.desactivate_frpt()}$\m@th#1\latex@lhook$}%
}
\let\latex@rightarrow\rightarrow
\renewrobustcmd{\rightarrow}{%
\mathrel{\mathpalette\do@rightarrow\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\do@rightarrow}[2]{%
\hbox{\directlua{polyglossia.desactivate_frpt()}$\m@th#1\latex@rightarrow$}%
}
\makeatother
\fi
\begin{document}
\fff

\fff
AAA $\hookrightarrow$ \fff.\\
AAA \fff BBBB.
\showoutput
\end{document}
```